# ReactJS: This.props.toggleModal is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent-child, state

I'm trying to access a parent method from a child to show a modal on screen and I'm getting the error: `This.props.toggleModal is not a function`. I'm passing the method down to the child so it can be called and using the correct state (I think). The button does call it's own method which in turn calls the parent. The modal component sits inside App.js.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super()
this.state = {
    isOpen: false
 }
}
toggleModal = () => {
this.setState({
  isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
});
console.log('Open');
}
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Modal toggleModal={this.toggleModal} show={this.state.isOpen}
          onClose={this.toggleModal}>
          Here's some content for the modal
    </Modal>
    <div className="container">
      <Header/>
      <main>
        <Route path="/users"
           children={({ match, ...rest }) => (
             <TransitionGroup component={firstChild}>
               {match && <UserList {...rest} />}
             </TransitionGroup>
        )}/>
        ...
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

**SearchBar.js** - (located inside the user page)

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  type: this.props.type,
  value: ''
};
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (nextProps.type !== this.props.type) {
  this.setState({ type: nextProps.type });
}
};
handleClick = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("Clicked!!!");
this.props.toggleModal();
};
handleChange = e => {
  console.log(this.state.type);
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
};

render () {
const isUser = this.state.type;
let rightContent = null;
if (isUser === "tour" || isUser === "venue") {
rightContent =
<div className="column">
  <div className="float-right"><button className="add-new" onClick={this.handleClick}>Add New</button></div>
</div>
} else {
rightContent =
<div className="column">
    <div className="float-right">
      <div className="results-block">
        <b>0</b>/<small>292</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
return (
<div className="row main-search">
  <div className="column">
      <form action="">
        <fieldset>
          <label htmlFor="search">
            <input type="text"
                placeholder="Start typing..."
                id="search-box"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.value} />
          </label>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
  {rightContent}
</div>
)
}
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: I don't see you using SearchBar component in App.js can you explain where have you used SearchBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check IF you getting toggleModal as props in your User Page Compoenent. If yes then pass it explicitly like to SearchBar

```
<SearchBar toggleModal = {this.props.toggleModal } /> // plus your rest of the props
```

Comment: This was almost it! `toggleModal={this.toggleModal}` and then from within the searchBar component click method I had `this.props.toggleModal();`, Thanks.

Comment: Cheers Buddy : D

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind toggleModal with this in constructor so that use it as this.toggleModal.
EX.

```
this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
```

check this ReactJs doc for more info.
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: This is not necessary for arrow functions inside class like the one he has given above.

Comment: his toggleModal already use the arrow function, I believe this is not an issue

Comment: your code looks ok, so I will guess according to your error message, you typo "this" into "This" (try to check this error)